# Using quotes within command substitution

Tags: bash, shell

I don't understand why this works

```
dateCMD=$(date -d "4 hours ago")
echo $dateCMD
Tue Oct 18 02:20:34 AEDT 2016
```

and this works

```
dateCMD="date"
$dateCMD
Tue Oct 18 06:23:19 AEDT 2016
```

But not this

```
dateCMD='date -d "4 hours ago"'
$($dateCMD)
date: extra operand ‘ago"’
```

How can I get this last case to work?

Comment: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: you don't want to do that. Use a function instead.

```
dateCMD () {
  date -d "4 hours ago"
}

dateCMD
```

Long answer: quotes in the value of a parameter are not "syntactic" quotes; they are just regular data. When you write

```
dateCMD='date -d "4 hours ago"'
$($dateCMD)
```

It is evaluated as follows:

1. `$dateCMD` expands to `date -d "4 hours ago"`
2. The expansion is split into the words `date`, `-d`, `"4`, `hours`, and `ago"`. The quotes are not treated specially.
3. The first word, `date`, is treated as the command with the rest of the words passed as distinct arguments.
4. `date` treates `"4` as the argument to the `-d` option. Since `date` takes only one additional positional argument (the format string), it takes `hours` as that argument, then complains that `ago` is an extra operand.

Comment: Nice explanation for why it doesn't work, thanks. I also realised `eval` would work (with the obvious security caveats), and anubhava's array answer was interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Use BASH array to make it work:

```
dateCMD=(date -d "4 hours ago")
"${dateCMD[@]}"
Mon Oct 17 11:38:54 EDT 2016
```

I was typing explanation on your quoting problem but then I noticed very well explained answer from @chepner so avoided adding redundant information in my answer.

Comment: Interesting solution for bash 4. Thanks. I also found `eval` will work.

Comment: Not just BASH 4 this should work with BASH 3.2 as well.

Comment: You are right. I didn't realise arrays could also be used in Bash 3.2 Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get the last case to work, you can use eval

Of course you should not use eval on any user input without completely validating that input.

```
dateCMD='date -d "4 hours ago"'
eval $dateCMD
```